# How to control the used memory in matlab standalone application using mldivide?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, matlab-compiler, pbs

In order to do large computation I moved from my personal computer to a cluster. Therefore, I have to use the PBS software (Portable Batch System) and to compile my code with the `mcc` command

```
mcc -I $workdir -l -m $workdir/$source.m
```

Doing so, a program which ran correctly on my computer with 16GB of RAM is using more than 60GB on the cluster (reported by the PBS output). If I allow less memory in my PBS launcher (`PBS -l select=1:mem=40000mb`), the computation ends with the error

```
>> PBS: job killed: mem 67088760kb exceeded limit 63120000kb
```

during an `mldivide` execution.

Is there a way to give a memory limit to compiled MATLAB application? Especially in the `mldivide` function?

The line which is a problem is :

```
sol=k\f;
```

On my computer this line display the following comment (requested by `spparms('spumoni',2)`)

```
sp\: bandwidth = 12514+1+12514.
sp\: is A diagonal? no.
sp\: is band density (0.01) > bandden (0.50) to try banded solver? no.
sp\: is A triangular? no.
sp\: is A morally triangular? no.
sp\: is A a candidate for Cholesky (symmetric, real positive diagonal)? no.
sp\: use Unsymmetric MultiFrontal PACKage with Control parameters:
UMFPACK V5.0.0 (May 5, 2006), Control:
    Matrix entry defined as: double
    Int (generic integer) defined as: UF_long

    0: print level: 2
    1: dense row parameter:    0.2
        "dense" rows have    > max (16, (0.2)*16*sqrt(n_col) entries)
    2: dense column parameter: 0.2
        "dense" columns have > max (16, (0.2)*16*sqrt(n_row) entries)
    3: pivot tolerance: 0.1
    4: block size for dense matrix kernels: 32
    5: strategy: 0 (auto)
    6: initial allocation ratio: 0.7
    7: max iterative refinement steps: 2
    12: 2-by-2 pivot tolerance: 0.01
    13: Q fixed during numerical factorization: 0 (auto)
    14: AMD dense row/col parameter:    10
       "dense" rows/columns have > max (16, (10)*sqrt(n)) entries
        Only used if the AMD ordering is used.
    15: diagonal pivot tolerance: 0.001
        Only used if diagonal pivoting is attempted.
    16: scaling: 1 (divide each row by sum of abs. values in each row)
    17: frontal matrix allocation ratio: 0.5
    18: drop tolerance: 0
    19: AMD and COLAMD aggressive absorption: 1 (yes)

    The following options can only be changed at compile-time:
    8: BLAS library used:  Fortran BLAS.  size of BLAS integer: 8
    9: compiled for MATLAB
    10: CPU timer is POSIX times ( ) routine.
    11: compiled for normal operation (debugging disabled)
    computer/operating system: Linux
    size of int: 4 UF_long: 8 Int: 8 pointer: 8 double: 8 Entry: 8 (in bytes)

sp\: is UMFPACK's symbolic LU factorization (with automatic reordering) successful? yes.
sp\: is UMFPACK's numeric LU factorization successful? yes.
sp\: is UMFPACK's triangular solve successful? yes.
sp\: UMFPACK Statistics:
UMFPACK V5.0.0 (May 5, 2006), Info:
    matrix entry defined as:          double
    Int (generic integer) defined as: UF_long
    BLAS library used: Fortran BLAS.  size of BLAS integer: 8
    MATLAB:                           yes.
    CPU timer:                        POSIX times ( ) routine.
    number of rows in matrix A:       16300
    number of columns in matrix A:    16300
    entries in matrix A:              1357892
    memory usage reported in:         16-byte Units
    size of int:                      4 bytes
    size of UF_long:                  8 bytes
    size of pointer:                  8 bytes
    size of numerical entry:          8 bytes

    strategy used:                    symmetric 2-by-2
    ordering used:                    amd on A+A'
    modify Q during factorization:    no
    prefer diagonal pivoting:         yes
    pivots with zero Markowitz cost:               0
    submatrix S after removing zero-cost pivots:
        number of "dense" rows:                    400
        number of "dense" columns:                 0
        number of empty rows:                      0
        number of empty columns                    0
        submatrix S square and diagonal preserved
    pattern of square submatrix S:
        number rows and columns                    16300
        symmetry of nonzero pattern:               0.996031
        nz in S+S' (excl. diagonal):               1348694
        nz on diagonal of matrix S:                14530
        fraction of nz on diagonal:                0.891411
    2-by-2 pivoting to place large entries on diagonal:
        # of small diagonal entries of S:          1770
        # unmatched:                               450
        symmetry of P2*S:                          0.724892
        nz in P2*S+(P2*S)' (excl. diag.):          1711248
        nz on diagonal of P2*S:                    15850
        fraction of nz on diag of P2*S:            0.972393
    AMD statistics, for strict diagonal pivoting:
        est. flops for LU factorization:           4.34967e+10
        est. nz in L+U (incl. diagonal):           26802242
        est. largest front (# entries):            8898289
        est. max nz in any column of L:            2983
        number of "dense" rows/columns in S+S':    0
    symbolic factorization defragmentations:       0
    symbolic memory usage (Units):                 3194290
    symbolic memory usage (MBytes):                48.7
    Symbolic size (Units):                         52076
    Symbolic size (MBytes):                        1
    symbolic factorization CPU time (sec):         0.20
    symbolic factorization wallclock time(sec):    0.20

    matrix scaled: yes (divided each row by sum of abs values in each row)
    minimum sum (abs (rows of A)):              3.15171e+10
    maximum sum (abs (rows of A)):              4.95863e+15

    symbolic/numeric factorization:      upper bound               actual      %
    variable-sized part of Numeric object:
        initial size (Units)                 2943251              2926948    99%
        peak size (Units)                   84730898             45751848    54%
        final size (Units)                  68529055             24858975    36%
    Numeric final size (Units)              68618741             24940511    36%
    Numeric final size (MBytes)               1047.0                380.6    36%
    peak memory usage (Units)               84978134             45999084    54%
    peak memory usage (MBytes)                1296.7                701.9    54%
    numeric factorization flops          5.14527e+11          1.24853e+11    24%
    nz in L (incl diagonal)                 50386877             28415032    56%
    nz in U (incl diagonal)                 74049732             20536978    28%
    nz in L+U (incl diagonal)              124420309             48935710    39%
    largest front (# entries)               28297269             21206024    75%
    largest # rows in front                     4815                 4651    97%
    largest # columns in front                  6715                 4638    69%

    initial allocation ratio used:                 0.272
    # of forced updates due to frontal growth:     25
    number of off-diagonal pivots:                 822
    nz in L (incl diagonal), if none dropped       28415032
    nz in U (incl diagonal), if none dropped       20536978
    number of small entries dropped                0
    nonzeros on diagonal of U:                     16300
    min abs. value on diagonal of U:               3.61e-09
    max abs. value on diagonal of U:               2.39e+02
    estimate of reciprocal of condition number:    1.51e-11
    indices in compressed pattern:                 738439
    numerical values stored in Numeric object:     48977820
    numeric factorization defragmentations:        4
    numeric factorization reallocations:           4
    costly numeric factorization reallocations:    2
    numeric factorization CPU time (sec):          60.92
    numeric factorization wallclock time (sec):    19.62
    numeric factorization mflops (CPU time):       2049.46
    numeric factorization mflops (wallclock):      6363.56
    symbolic + numeric CPU time (sec):             61.12
    symbolic + numeric mflops (CPU time):          2042.75
    symbolic + numeric wall clock time (sec):      19.82
    symbolic + numeric mflops (wall clock):        6299.35

    solve flops:                                   3.13032e+08
    iterative refinement steps taken:              1
    iterative refinement steps attempted:          2
    sparse backward error omega1:                  4.69e-16
    sparse backward error omega2:                  0.00e+00
    solve CPU time (sec):                          0.73
    solve wall clock time (sec):                   0.30
    solve mflops (CPU time):                       428.81
    solve mflops (wall clock time):                1043.44

    total symbolic + numeric + solve flops:        1.25166e+11
    total symbolic + numeric + solve CPU time:     61.85
    total symbolic + numeric + solve mflops (CPU): 2023.70
    total symbolic+numeric+solve wall clock time:  20.55
    total symbolic+numeric+solve mflops(wallclock) 6090.81
```

I believe the problem might comes from the `numerical values stored in Numeric object:     48977820` which is very large.

Comment: Sounds like you're not slicing things correctly, so MATLAB (or the compiled app) is forced to put deep copies of some huge array on each worker. Could you post the relevant code, preferably in [MWE](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) form?

Comment: @Rody Thanks for the formatting. What do you mean by slicing things ?
I have add the code line but the code to get the matrix `k` and vector `f` cannot be summarized on this post.

Comment: Well, for one thing, the operator `\` is not `rdivide`, but `mldivide` -- you're trying to solve a linear system there. That makes  this already less mysterious :)

Comment: My mistake, thanks for noticing it. It's corrected.